# Why is every simple object in the category of abelian groups simple in the category of groups?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I'm not asking for a proof that every simple abelian group is simple; that's a fairly trivial question. To lead into my real question, I started thinking about this question:

> Let $\cal C$ be a category with a terminal object, and let $\cal B$ be a full subcategory which contains a terminal object from $\cal C$ (we can assume $\cal B$ is isomorphism closed). If $X$ is an object of $\cal B$ which is simple in $\cal B$, does it follow that $X$ is a simple object of $\cal C$?

The answer to this question is false by considering the category

$\hskip2in$[image]

and considering the subcategory

$\hskip2in$[image]

In these examples, $X$ is simple in the latter but not the former. This made me wonder

> What is special about the relationship between **Grp** and **Ab** that implies every simple object of **Ab** is simple in **Grp**?

I thought it might be because the inclusion functor from **Ab** to **Grp** has a left adjoint (the abelianization functor), but this is also true in the categories above (collapse $Y$ to $X$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathsf{Ab}$ is closed under quotients taken in $\mathsf{Grp}$.